# Setting up Quota for Subsites

Tags: 2007, quota, administration

I expect to have 1000+ subsites in a site-collection and would like to setup a quota for the subsites, is that possible in SharePoint 2007 & how ?

Comment: 1000+ subsites can create some serious topology and administration issues.  If you are even remotely concerned about setting quotas then I'm wondering how you are going to manage that content database.

Comment: so, we have to restrict the site-collection administrator from creating subsites if (s)he exceeds "X" number of subsites...? if yes, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide the IA ( information Architecture ) before the start of provisioning, ....This will help to decide site structuring DEEP vs WIDE

DEEP Structure :  having one sitecollection to house all the sites requests as subsites

-> cannot limit the site quotas
-> security nightmare (1000+ sites)
-> as the content DB grows , it would be difficult to backup, migrate and restore

WIDE Structure : Each request a seperate site collections

-> Controlled Quote Sizes
-> manageable security
-> Isolated and easy to backup and restore
-> room to grow

1000+ subsites is a nightmare to manage

Read [this](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2009/09/classification-and-structuring-of.html) article.

Plan ahead and manage easily(wide).. OR no plan (DEEP), cab be controlled by constant monitoring :)

Answer (score 4):

Quota is only available on Site Collection level.

Comment: so there is no way to restrict the subsites growth?

Comment: no. this is by design. you have to use site collection to achive this.

Answer (score 2):

As Wictor say quota can only be set on site collection -no workaround.

An alternative is to monitor site sizes using Storage Management

> `http://<site_collection>/_layouts/storman.aspx`

but be aware that this functionality has been removed in SharePoint 2010 since it caused performance issues for end users.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party utility that can help you manage this, try the SpeakTech [governance kit](http://sharepointgovernancekit.com/Default.aspx) which does much as well as allow for Subsite Quotas, be advised it is expensive though.