# Setting up Quota for Subsites in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, quota

In SharePoint 2010, is it possible to set a storage quota on individual sub-sites within a site collection?

According to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/setting-up-quota-for-subsites), it is not possible to do so SharePoint 2007. I'm curious if things are any different with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quota templates are applied at the site collection level in SharePoint 2010 as well. See this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263223.aspx) for more info.